# Methods, more than one return?

Tags: methods, boolean, return

I have the following method:

From what I learned methods which are not voids need a return. For the following examples I can see two returns, once after if(), and one at the end. 
For this example if String s is not a digit it will return the boolean as false. Which makes sense. If it is a digit then it will check whether it is in the interval. I guess I am confused regarding whether we can have multiple returns in such cases and what the limitations are, if there are any. thank you.

```
    private boolean ElementBienFormat(String s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (!Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    int n = Integer.valueOf(s);

    return (n>=0 && n <=255);
```

Comment: It is perfectly fine to have multiple `return` statements in a method. Only one of the returns will be executed. Once one of the `return`s happens, the program leaves the method and will not get to the other one.

Answer (score 1):

A method will "quit" (return) when control reaches a `return`. So in this case as soon as a character is not a digit in the input `String` control will go back to the caller (with the appropriate value).

```
boolean success = ElementBienFormat( "a" ); // <-- control would go back here with the value of false.
```

Another quick note is that a `void` method can have multiple `return` statements as well

```
private void Method( int n )
{
    if( n < 0 )
       return; 

    //...

    //implicit
    //return;
}
```